# How to measure syndromes in QEC

Tags: quantum-state, error-correction

Shor's $9$ Qubit code. Imagine that we encode the state $|\psi \rangle =α|0\rangle+β|1\rangle$ using Shor's $9$ qubit code, then an $X$ error occurs on the 8th qubit of the encoded state $|E(\psi) \rangle$

This is

$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt2}( \alpha (| 000 \rangle + | 111 \rangle) ( | 000 \rangle + | 111 \rangle) ( | 010 \rangle + | 101 \rangle) \\ + \beta ( | 000 \rangle - | 111 \rangle)( | 000 \rangle - | 111 \rangle)( | 010 \rangle - | 101 \rangle))$$

We now decode the encoded state, starting by applying the bit-flip code decoding algorithm.

How do you find the syndromes measured by the algorithm, see [https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~csxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ecsxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf)?

Comment: For sure I'm late, but you can play around with this code and check step by step what is being done in the Shor's 9-qubit algorithm for correcting quantum errors: https://github.com/sebastianvromero/qecc_shor9q . Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it clear how the syndrome measurement for $3$ qubit bit-flip code is done that is described in the same [source](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ecsxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf) with this [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22%7Ese9b%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D,%22gates%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:%22%7Erhq8%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7Ese9b%22,%22name%22:%22Encoding%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D)? If yes then is it clear how this can be done for $9$ qubit code with this [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22%7E7gjp%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D,%22gates%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:%22%7Erhq8%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7Ese9b%22,%22name%22:%22Encoding%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7E7gjp%22,%22name%22:%229%20qubit%20code%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D) for bit-flip error? If no here are some ideas that might help.

---

**A toy model example about what is happening in these codes.** Imagine we have a Bell state $|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$. Imagine there is a probability that we will have an $X$ error (bit-flip error) on one of the qubits and we want to know if we had an error. Here is the circuit constructed with help of IBM quantum experience:

[image]

**This is not an error-correcting code, this is a toy model on which one can see how syndrome measurement can be done.** In the error detection part if we will not have an error (we assume the possibility of only one error) then the measurement will yield $0$, otherwise, if we will have an error then we will measure $1$. If we had an error, then applying an $X$ gate on one of the qubits will recreate the initial $|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$.

The bit-flip error detecting part here (and in $3$ qubit bit-flip code or $9$ qubit code) is a parity check: checks if there are even number of $1$s in the $2$ controlling qubits. So if we have $|00 \rangle$ or $|11\rangle$ (or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle$)) the parity is even and the output qubit will be in $|0\rangle$ state. If we have $|01 \rangle$ or $|01\rangle$ (or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle + |01\rangle$)) the parity is odd and the output qubit will be in $|1\rangle$ state. If this part is clear I suggest looking at two circuit links (created with quirk) provided at the beginning of the answer.

---

**For the error on the $8$th qubit.** For $9$ qubit code there are $6$ parity check measurements for $6$ pairs of qubits that can be seen in the mentioned [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22%7E7gjp%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D,%22gates%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:%22%7Erhq8%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7Ese9b%22,%22name%22:%22Encoding%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7E7gjp%22,%22name%22:%229%20qubit%20code%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D). The parity between all $6$ pairs of qubits is even when we don't have an error and the measured syndrome is $00,00,00$. If an $X$ error is acquired, one or two parities will be odd and we will notice it in sydrome measurement procedure. For the example mentioned in the question ($8$th qubit got an error) the parity is odd for last two pairs of qubits that is why we will measure $00,00,11$ syndrome. If $9$th qubit has an error the parity will be odd only for the last pair of qubits (last two qubits) and the syndrome will be $00,00,01$. If the error has acquired on the $7$th qubit then the syndrome will be $00,00,10$, because the parity is odd only for the penultimate pair of qubits (pair that consists of $6$th and $7$th qubits). If we know on which qubit an $X$ error has acquired we can apply on that qubit an $X$ gate that will correct the acquired error.

The parity checks for Shore's $9$ qubit code can also be done with this [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B1,1,1,1,1,1,%22%7Es0r0%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22%5D,%5B1,1,1,1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,%22Z%22,%22Z%22%5D,%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D%5D,%22gates%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:%22%7Es0r0%22,%22name%22:%22Encoding%22,%22circuit%22:%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D%5D%7D%7D%5D%7D) by using an operator measurement technique.

Comment: This is difficult stuff, thanks

Comment: @Trajan, you are welcome.